# Compute the the tangent line for the curve obtained by intersecting two surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let C be the curve obtained by intersecting $x^3 + 2xy + yz = 7$ and $3x^2 - yz = 1$. Find the parametric equations of the tangent line to C at $P = (1,2,1)$.

So I first set the equations equal to each other:

$x^3 + 2xy + yz - 7 = 3x^2 - yz - 1$

I simplified to: $x^3 + 2xy + 2yz - 3x^2 - 6 = 0$

I find the gradient:

$\langle 3x^2 + 2y - 6x, 2x + 2z, 2y \rangle$

I use the values of $P$ in the gradient and get $\langle 1,4,4\rangle$

I conclude that I should get the line $\langle 1,2,1\rangle + \langle 1,4,4\rangle t$

This is the wrong answer. The correct answer is

$x = 1 - 4t \quad y = 2 + 26t\quad  z = 1 - 25t$

I get that I could find the gradient of each equation, get the vector, and find the cross product to get the correct answer, but I don't get why what I did does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterize tangent line  $ (x,y) $ *projection* by adding the given equations:

$ x^3 + 3 x^2 + 2 x y  -8 =0 $ at $(1,2), $ then re-parameterize to include $z$.

$$ \langle 1,2,1\rangle + \langle 1,4,4\rangle t $$

EDIT 1:

Find parameterization of 3D curve of intersection and find tangent in the usual way by differentiation w.r.t. $t$.

I have no smart parametrization for curve of intersection but on x-basis (x=t) we may take

$$ \left(t, \frac{(8-t^3-3 t^2)}{2 t },\frac{2t (3 t^2-1)}{(8-t^3-3 t^2)}\right)$$

The surface you gave

$$ (x^3 + 2 xy + y z - 7) - (3 x^2 - y z - 1)==0 $$

and other two have common line of concurrency and  with method you indicate for surface gradient normal vectors gives no pure tangential  but more towards a normal at the given point. When you seek a line but still stay with another surface you are getting to nowhere.

Comment: Yes, I know this solution works as well, but I don't understand why my solution does not work.

Comment: Are you looking for normal or tangent?

Comment: the tangent line

Comment: t does not look like that. In the plot the line is not tangential but somewhere between normal and bi-normal!